# How can I improve my PHP sanitization without using PDO

Tags: php, sql-injection, sanitization

I have written a short function for sanitizing strings/variables before being being used in SQL queries:

```
function cleanstring($sanitize, $maxlength=10, $minlength=0){
    if(strlen($sanitize) <= $maxlength && strlen($sanitize) >= $minlength){
    $sanitize = substr(mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($sanitize)), 0, $maxlength);
}
else{
    include("includes/header.php");
    exit("Error!");
    }

return $sanitize;
}
```

called using:

```
$variable = cleanstring($_POST['someInput'], 5, 5)
```

would define the length of the string, clean it using real_escape_string and strip_tags and then use substr() to ensure that the returned data still matches the length criteria.

Is there any way that I can improve this sanitization function, without using PDOs?

Comment: Your PHP code will be bad no matter what you do if you keep using the `mysql` extension... Besides that, html-related escaping should be done on display and not when storing data.

Comment: You are actually breaking your escaped data!  Apply your maximum length before escaping for MySQL.  Also, this really is a mess.  Why not use prepared queries?

Comment: reinventing the wheel ? Good luck :)

Comment: You might want to read up on some background for what you're trying to do here: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/). Also, this is possibly better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: why not use [Sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the point (or making it too big of a point).  **Any time** you mix control characters with data, there needs to be a way to escape these control characters so they are interpreted as data.

In web programming, there are a few areas:

- SQL (different per database)
- command shell
- URIs
- HTML Attributes
- HTML Content
- JavaScript

Each one calls for a unique method of escaping.  Sometimes there are multiple levels of escaping, like encoding a URI and then encoding that into an `href=""` attribute.

Your function is technically "safe", but kind of a mess.  Wouldn't you prefer to give the user an error rather than silently truncate their input?  Also, what if someone as making a comment about `When I put <strong> tags around the gadget, it breaks?` ... your code will remove the `<strong>`.  But `<` and `>` are completely safe to insert into SQL.

I suggest you simply use the methods that have been created for each of the items above.

- MySQL: `"'" . mysqli_real_escape_string(...) . "'"`, possibly `intval` in some cases.
- command shell: `escapeshellargI(...)`
- URIs: `urlencode()`
- HTML Attributes: `'"' . htmlspecialchars(..., ENT_QUOTES) . '"'`
- HTML Content: `htmlspecialchars(...)
- JavaScript: `json_encode(...)` possibly wrapped in the encoding for HTML, depending on context.

You can wrap some of these into shorter functions for convenience:

```
function QA($val)
{
    return '"' . htmlspecialchars($val, ENT_QUOTES) . '"';
}
```

etc...

**But the main point is to 100% of the time prevent data from being read as control characters.**

Answer (score 0):

Don't `strip_tags` and don't do `mysql_real_excape_string`!!!
In printing you need to think whether you want to print it with `strip_tags`, `htmlspecialchars` or something else, not in the sanitization. 
Instead of `mysql_real_excape_string` use prepared statements.
Use also filters to sanitization the string as Email or something else.